# Apply git .gitignore rules to an existing repository

Tags: git

I started using git with an xcode project and have recently discovered that I can use .gitignore and .gitattributes files to ignore the noise from the compiler and system.  **Now that I have the .gitignore and .gitattributes files in place, how can I "apply" the new ignore rules and get rid of the crud from version control?**

My .gitignore file is:

```
# xcode noise
*.modelv3
*.pbxuser
*.perspective
*.perspectivev3
*.pyc
*~.nib/
build/*

# Textmate - if you build your xcode projects with it
*.tm_build_errors

# old skool
.svn

# osx noise
.DS_Store
profile
```

And my .gitattributes file is:

```
*.pbxproj -crlf -diff -merge
```

Thanks!

Comment: +1 The link at Chris's comment here worked better for me than anything on this page.

Comment: **No no no,** [this is the right way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7532131/288906). Most suggested answers re-commit ALL the files.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

use `git rm --cached` for files and `git rm -r --cached` for the `build/` directory

Comment: While that's *accurate*, I arrived from Google and found that an *unhelpful* answer because that is how to do it one file at a time. Far more helpful and efficient would be an answer like Chris Johnsen's that tells you how to kill all of the should-be-ignored files in one step.

Comment: This is a better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1139797/743957

Comment: This doesn't have to be one file at a time. Run `git rm -r --cached *` to purge everything.

Comment: Even [better answer, it just re-applies gitignore](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7532131/288906) correctly

Answer (score 64):

Here is one way to “untrack” any files that are would otherwise be ignored under the current set of exclude patterns:

```
(GIT_INDEX_FILE=some-non-existent-file \
 git ls-files --exclude-standard --others --directory --ignored -z) |
xargs -0 git rm --cached -r --ignore-unmatch --
```

This leaves the files in your working directory but removes them from the index.

The trick used here is to provide a non-existent index file to *git ls-files* so that it thinks there are no tracked files. The shell code above asks for all the files that would be ignored if the index were empty and then removes them from the actual index with *git rm*.

After the files have been “untracked”, use *git status* to verify that nothing important was removed (if so adjust your exclude patterns and use `git reset -- path` to restore the removed index entry). Then make a new commit that leaves out the “crud”.

The “crud” will still be in any old commits. You can use [*git filter-branch*](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) to produce  clean versions of the old commits if you really need a clean history (n.b. using *git filter-branch* will “rewrite history”, so it should not be undertaken lightly if you have any collaborators that have pulled any of your historical commits after the “crud” was *first* introduced).

Comment: This solution made more sense for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring

Comment: How is this command executed? Pasting it into a terminal gives the error `-bash: git: command not found`, yet I can execute git commands in that directory.

Comment: @Answerbot: What does `type git` say? It sounds like it is an alias (or shell function?). The fact that `git` is not just an normal, external command for you is causing the shell to fail when combined with the temporary environment variable assignment (e.g. `FOO=bar git …` does not expand your `git` alias, and your PATH has no `git`). Either one would also fail with *xargs* since *xargs* is execing your commands itself, not using the shell to do it. You either need to “expand” your *git* uses to match your alias/function, or use an external wrapper script that bundles the same effects.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response @ChrisJohnsen . `type git` returns `git is hashed (/usr/local/bin/git)`. Any good references on expanding git to match or using an external wrapper?

Comment: @Answerbot: Since your `git` does seem to be an external command my guess was wrong; the expansion or wrapping is not applicable since your `git` is not an alias or shell function. I wrote the command to be pasted into a (Bourne compatible) shell, and it does work for me in *ksh*, *bash*, and *zsh*. Right now, I have no other guesses as to why your shell produced those symptoms.

Answer (score 12):

If you are already tracking files you want to ignore, you have to remove them with

```
git rm --cached <file>
```

Git won't ignore files which are already tracked (i.e. you added them with git add ).

Comment: This command always sets the file as deleted for me....

Comment: @MladenDanic That's alright, git is saying that it views the file as deleted. The file won't actually be deleted because of the '--cached' operator, but git effectively views it as removed now.

Comment: But if I am not mistaken it will delete it from the remote repository, right?

Comment: Yes, if you push afterwards. But I think that is exactly what you want if you do this.

Answer (score 2):

`mv the_file_i_want_to_ignore the_file_i_want_to_ignore.back`

`git rm the_file_i_want_to_ignore`

`mv the_file_i_want_to_ignore.back the_file_i_want_to_ignore`

`git status`

`git commit -m 'ignore a bunch of stuff i should have ignored before'`

this a bit of a manual workflow but its how i've done this in the past.

Comment: You really want to use `git rm --cached`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the files completely, then here's a [handy reference from Github](http://help.github.com/removing-sensitive-data/).

Be warned that:

1. This will rewrite your history, so it's probably only worth doing before you publish your repo.
2. Remember that the old shas will still be in the object database, but the guide I've linked to will show you how to deal with those as well.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't have to 'apply' the changes. simply put the .gitignore file in your home directory (if you want it to be global) or in your project root (if you want it to be unique only to that project).

**Edit:** It occurs to me that you might be having this problem because you've added the files you don't want to track already. Here's what the gitignore man page has to say about that:

> Note that all the gitignore files really concern only files that are not already tracked by git; in order to ignore uncommitted changes in already tracked files, please refer to the git update-index --assume-unchanged documentation.

Comment: The the people that dislike this answer... please offer feedback as to why you don't like it. It's not helpful to just downvote it without a reason.