# Applying .gitignore to committed files

Tags: git

I have committed loads of files that I now want to ignore. How can I tell git to now ignore these files from future commits?

EDIT: I do want to remove them from the repository too. They are files created after ever build or for user-specific tooling support.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.gitignore file not ignoring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring)

Comment: @Wooble The answer may be similar, but this question exactly describes the problem I was faced with and needed to solve.

Comment: This is the answer that directly addresses the title question with minimal changes to your git repo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245961/3543437

Answer (score 632, accepted):

1. Edit `.gitignore` to match the file you want to ignore
2. `git rm --cached /path/to/file`

See also:

- [How do I git rm a file without deleting it from disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273108/how-do-i-git-rm-a-file-without-deleting-it-from-disk)
- [Remove a file from a Git repository without deleting it from the local filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/git-remove-a-file-from-the-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesys)
- [Ignoring a directory from a Git repo after it's been added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618612/git-rm-cached-directory)

Comment: There's a lot of files though. I don't want to have do this for every single one

Comment: Are the files in any common directories? If not, the problem reduces to a shell usage question, not a git one.

Comment: There does need to be a 'I forgot to add my .gitignore until after my initial commit' mode.

Comment: 'I forgot to add my .gitignore until after my initial commit' and the answer is the post below this one. It works!

Comment: It asked me to add flag -r to be able to do so.

Comment: Another way to fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608337/applying-hgignore-file-to-already-committed-file-mercurial-repo

Comment: Does this need to be done by every developer or just once?

Answer (score 718):

After editing `.gitignore` to match the ignored files, you can do `git ls-files -ci --exclude-standard` to see the files that are included in the exclude lists; you can then do

- Linux/MacOS: `git ls-files -ci --exclude-standard -z | xargs -0 git rm --cached`
- Windows (PowerShell): `git ls-files -ci --exclude-standard | % { git rm --cached "$_" }`
- Windows (cmd.exe): `for /F "tokens=*" %a in ('git ls-files -ci --exclude-standard') do @git rm --cached "%a"`

to remove them from the repository (without deleting them from disk).

**Edit**: You can also add this as an alias in your .gitconfig file so you can run it anytime you like. Just add the following line under the [alias] section (modify as needed for Windows or Mac):

```
apply-gitignore = !git ls-files -ci --exclude-standard -z | xargs -0 git rm --cached
```

(The `-r` flag in `xargs` prevents `git rm` from running on an empty result and printing out its usage message, but may only be supported by GNU findutils.  Other versions of `xargs` may or may not have a similar option.)

Now you can just type `git apply-gitignore` in your repo, and it'll do the work for you!

Comment: I think xargs for mac has no -r... or mine is buggy/old, I don't know... and why the `!` before git? well... mine one worked as `alias apply-gitignore="git ls-files -ci --exclude-standard -z | xargs -0 git rm --cached"`. tks!

Comment: On Windows `for /F "tokens=*" %a in ('git ls-files -ci --exclude-standard') do @git rm --cached "%a"`

Comment: This just removed my .gitignore files, not the files I wanted to ignore that were listed in the .gitignore files - was that the point?

Comment: @Hippyjim if the files are already committed (even though they were listed in .gitignore), and .gitignore is *not* yet committed, then that would be the expected result, otherwise, I'm not sure what is going on in your case.

Comment: But isn't this a bad idea as git rm will remove the files from other places on pull, even if you use --cached to avoid that locally?

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Much appreciated!

Comment: I got an error `xargs: git : Bad file number` using git 1.9.2. Using SourceTree's embedded git works fine, not sure why.

Comment: THIS is the answer. I also added a "git add .gitignore" to have that file in there so others don't add stuff. Nice one!

Comment: You usually do not get to re-elect an "Accepted" answer on SO. Unfortunately I've seen this a lot here. The best thing to do is to scroll to the bottom and read all the answers before going with just one of them (upvotes dont always make for the best answer btw, ive found gems with NEGATIVE votes as well, however in this instance, that is clearly not the case) but anyway, excellent answer this is, I'll accept this is the real answer.

Comment: The one that worked for me is to change ~/.gitconfig
```apply-gitignore= !git ls-files -ci --exclude-standard -z | xargs -0 git rm --cached
```
This is based on @Felipe-sabino response but without the quotes and using a ```!git``` hint. I'm using git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)

Comment: @Zero3 This is what happens when you have to dive into the plumbing instead of just using porcelain commands

Comment: For mac users, `-r` is default and is not accepted by BSD versions. So remove `-r`.

Comment: NOTE: that this will add "remove those files" into your git. You will keep your local files due to "--cached" argument, however if you have to go back into your history before the deletion and return again, git will look into the "remove those files" and delete it from your local folder. So you should be careful with it.

Comment: I have done both steps but removed files to be ignored from commits all of them ended in a "staged files" area in the SourceTree

Comment: Hi, the `git ls-files -ci --exclude-standard -z | xargs -0 git rm --cached` command results in `xargs: cannot fork` at me (on Windows). What can I do with this?

Comment: Is it possible to remove such files from all previous commits?

Answer (score 211):

to leave the file in the repo but ignore future changes to it:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

and to undo this:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

to find out which files have been set this way:

```
git ls-files -v|grep '^h'
```

credit for the original answer to 
http://blog.pagebakers.nl/2009/01/29/git-ignoring-changes-in-tracked-files/

Comment: Chronial has a great answer for doing this recursively for a directory:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16346756/1101076

Comment: I wanted to commit an IDE config but not track unnecessary changes to it.
This works, though I'm not sure if it'll work for others who check out the repository.
It can be combined with `git ls-files -ci --exclude-standard -z | xargs -0 git update-index --assume-unchanged` if that helps.

Comment: This is the _only_ answer that does precisely what the title question asks for. PERFECT! Most of these other answers were messing with files needlessly.

Comment: This is the exactly right answer for the question. Using commands like `git rm --cached` will remove the file in repository, which doesn't meet the need of quizzer. Thank you. I really appreciate it. Your answer helps me a lot.

Comment: The last command, on windows, replace grep with findstr for the same result. git ls-files -v|findstr '^h'

Answer (score 206):

Be sure that your actual repo is the latest version and without ongoing changes

1. Edit `.gitignore` as you wish
2. `git rm -r --cached .` (remove all files)
3. `git add .` (re-add all files according to gitignore)

then commit as usual

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as the question specifically said there were a lot of files to remove.

Comment: Note that step 2 this can take a while if you have a big repository.

Comment: This just led to removal of *all* files from the index! [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125710/how-to-revert-a-git-rm-r) saved me: `git reset HEAD` (Remember to stash any changes)

Comment: Step 2 removes everything, yes, but step 3 should readd them all, except for the ones that fail due to .gitignore.

Answer (score 12):

Old question, but some of us are in `git-posh` (powershell). This is the solution for that:

```
git ls-files -ci --exclude-standard | foreach { git rm --cached $_ }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Add your filename/file-path into the `.gitignore` file.
2. Now run command in git bash `git rm --cached file/path/from/root/folder`
3. Now commit your code using `git commit`.

Now the file should not get tracked in the `git status` command.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to forget / am too lazy to read what these git commands do. So I do it like this:

- I move all files, which I want to ignore, temporarily outside the repository
- I commit these "deleted files" in my git GUI (they are now untracked)
- I update the .gitignore file
- I move the files back into the repository (or delete them, if that was my intention)

Answer (score 1):

After editing .gitignore file.

```
git rm -r --cached ./ &&  git add ./ && git commit -a -m "Removing ignored files" && git push
```

Answer (score 0):

İf you already committed, you can use this:

1. Add folder path to .gitignore file.
2. Run this command for removing exe (for another file extensions, just write "*extension") files.
   `git rm --cached *exe`
3. Commit changes.

You should do this for every extension that you wanted to remove.

Answer (score 0):

If you are git rm'ing a lot of files (say, 100k), answers in this thread could be improved by processing the list of files (produced by `git ls-files -ci --exclude-standard`) in batches. (AFAIK, parallel processing will not work with git due to its index-locking mechanism.)

Example of batching in Powershell:

```
$files = git ls-files -ci --exclude-standard
$batchSize = 100

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i += $batchSize) {
    $batch = $files[$i..($i + $batchSize - 1)]
    git rm -f --cached $batch
}
```

On Windows, the upper bound on `$batchSize` is the limit of the command line length. For short paths, you might get away with larger a `$batchSize`.

Answer (score -3):

Follow these steps:

1. Add path to `gitignore` file
2. Run this command

   ```
   git rm -r --cached foldername
   ```
3. commit changes as usually.