# git push folder containing large file

Tags: git, push, ignore

In my git repository I have a folder (DATA) containing other folders containing large files.
I created a .gitignore file with the following text

```
DATA/
```

I tried to update the files in my repository and I got this error anyway

```
remote: warning: File DATA/segmentation/Feat_2.mat is 94.46 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50 MB
remote: warning: File DATA/segmentation/Feat_3.mat is 61.77 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50 MB
remote: warning: File DATA/segmentation/Feat_4.mat is 80.35 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50 MB
remote: warning: File DATA/segmentation/Feat_5.mat is 85.85 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50 MB
remote: warning: File DATA/segmentation/Feat_6.mat is 78.94 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50 MB
remote: warning: File DATA/segmentation/Feat_7.mat is 66.61 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected.
remote: error: Trace: 66ef415089784516b0d76ac2e639a7ac
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File DATA/segmentation/Feat_1.mat is 123.29 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100 MB
To https://github.com/gabboshow/smartscope_code.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/gabboshow/smartscope_code.git'
gabbo@gabbo-SATELLITE-L750:/media/Data/Condiviso/TUe/Smartscope_study/smartscope_code$
```

How can I fix the git push and continue committing my files ignoring all the files in the folder DATA?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you committed files in `DATA`, and then added it to the `.gitignore`, didn't you?

Ignoring an already committed file is a Git FAQ. The short answer is:

**`.gitignore` only applies to untracked files, i.e. files that have never been committed (or even `git add`ed).**

See for example:
[Applying .gitignore to committed files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527982/applying-gitignore-to-committed-files)

You will have to remove the large files from your repository to be able to push. Note that you must remove them from the history as well (by rewriting history); deleting them in a new commit is not enough.

Github has a nice page on how to do this, linked in your error message:
https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files

Comment: Thanks, but when I run java -jar bfg.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 50M I get Unable to access jarfile bfg.jar

Comment: @gabboshow: Sounds like you are not invoking bfg.jar correctly. Try invoking it with its full filesystem path. If you keep having problems, ask a new question.