# Remove a big set of old commits and shrink git folder

Tags: git

It's potentially a duplicated topic but the solutions founded here doesn't look enough.

We have a project with ~190MB of code and a git folder with ~6GB and a lot of commits that are not interesting anymore.

Supose my commits looks like:

A, B, C...Y, Z, AA, AB...FC, FD...GO

How I can delete history from B to FC plus shrink git folder and get only:

A, FD...GO

I believe that after that all developers should clone the repo again to avoid conflicts.

Again, sorry if it's a duplicated topic but I'm a bit confused about all the solutions for this kind of problem.

Comment: Are you *sure* the problem isn't binary blobs in your repository?

Comment: If the problem *is* binary blobs, then http://stackoverflow.com/a/24539614/6309 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/24693485/6309

Comment: @CodeGnome I'm sure it's not the problem. This project is old but still in production and I have a huge number of commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of older history, you could make a clone using the `--depth` param:

```
git clone --depth NUMBER_OF_COMMITS_TO_FD file:///path/to/original newrepo
```