# Confusion on gitignore file tracking

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm having trouble understanding exactly how the .gitignore file works.

Say I have the following .gitignore:

```
/db/*.sqlite3
/log/*.log
/public/uploads/*
```

On all of my computers, I have a file `/db/development.sqlite3`

My questions are:

1. If the file is already in the repository, will it pull down the version in the repo every time I git pull?
2. Do files in the gitignore file need to be untracked on all systems in order to not pull or push to or from the repo?
3. If I decide to add another line /tmp/** /* to my gitignore after the fact, do I need to go into each workstation/live server to untrack the files?  And do I need to push a version to the repo that has /tmp/** deleted?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is already in the repository, will it pull down the version in the repo every time I git pull?

- An already commited file will not be ignored. For doing that you need to do this [Applying .gitignore to committed files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527982/applying-gitignore-to-committed-files)

Do files in the gitignore file need to be untracked on all systems in order to not pull or push to or from the repo?

- This shouldn't be needed as long as you download the changes and merge it in your current branch. If you don't do that you could face some errors

If I decide to add another line /tmp/** /* to my gitignore after the fact, do I need to go into each workstation/live server to untrack the files? And do I need to push a version to the repo that has /tmp/** deleted?**

- The first part is answered above. You will need to push that version with this new path deleted

Comment: So basically, for any file or directory that I want ignored, if it is already commited, or in the repo, I just need to run `git rm` on that file or directory?

Comment: yes. That should work. I had this situation a couple of times and it is always a mess. You have to be careful and check that a branch is not overriding what the other task did so at the end the file is not ignored... But after a couple of tries you will get it work. Or may be in the first try, who knows...