# Can't ignore *.vssscc, *.vspscc files

Tags: git, github, tfs, git-tfs, git-tf

I'm using [Git-TF](https://gittf.codeplex.com/) (bridge between *Git* and *Team Foundation Version Control (tfvc)*)

`git tf pull` downloads ***.vssscc, .vspscc*** files into the repository and commits.  So if I use `git push` next, it uploads those files into remote repository which is not desired behavior for me.

I was trying to make `git tf pull` aware of **.gitignore** file. Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7532131/439130) I added following lines into the **.gitconfig**

```
[alias]
   apply-gitignore = !git ls-files -ci --exclude-standard -z | xargs -0r git rm --cached
```

and called `git apply-gitignore`.  As far as my understanding, it removes files from repository (not physically, just awareness).
Next I had to ran `git commit -a -m "TFS2Git"` and finally `git push -u origin master --force` which worked fine and pushed the source into remote repository (GitHub) without *unwanted files*.

Next, I did some fake updates and pulled remote source into local repository and checked-in to TFS via `git tf checkin`.  Unfortunately it actually deleted *unwanted files* from the solution.

Is there a workaround to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a .gitignore file using the Visual Studio IDE (Team Explorer | Settings | Source | Add .gitignore) it will automatically have the exclude patterns that you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I believe you are missing something here.  I'm not talking about IDE or VS git features.  **.gitignore** is already in there.  [Git-TF](https://gittf.codeplex.com/) is a tool that creates a bridge between Team Foundation Version Control (tfvc) and Git repository.  It works outside of the IDE and it is the one which ignores **.gitignore**

Comment: You should not have those files checked into TFS. So this should not even be a problem. Go delete the files from TFVC and the problem will go away. You can use .tfignore to prevent TFVC users checking in those sort of files...

Comment: I just removed the *.suo etc part from the title since those are not goes into the TFS (and thank you for reminding me that) But .vssscc, .vspscc I didn't know that, we can eliminate those files to be checked-in. I mean those files always gets check-in by visual studio. Let me research it little bit and I will get back to you. Thank you for the lead!