# gitignore not working on all files

Tags: git, file, ignore

I am trying to ignore some files from my project. I have the following extensions in *.gitignore*

```
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.tlog
*.cer
*.cat
*.inf
*.tmh
*.inf
```

I see the following file is ignored

```
D:\Projects\driver1\driver1\inter\Win32\Win7Debug\link.command.1.tlog
```

but the following file is seen as Modified, thus this one is not ignored.

```
D:\Projects\driver1\ioctlapp\inter\Debug\link.write.1.tlog
```

Why the second file isn't ignored and how can i fix the problem?

I took only 2 files from both, from ignored and not ignored files, but there are more files which I expect to ignore and they aren't.

Comment: Might be that the second file is already a tracked file? If so, it will not be ignored.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying .gitignore to committed files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527982/applying-gitignore-to-committed-files)

Answer (score 3):

That's most probably because you committed it *before* adding `*.tlog` in your `.gitignore`.

Use `git rm` to remove it from git and the commit the changes:

```
 git rm D:\Projects\driver1\ioctlapp\inter\Debug\link.write.1.tlog
 git commit -m 'Removed link.write.1.tlog'
```

Next time when you will edit it, it will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

First check if file is tracked `git ls-files --error-unmatch file_name`
If you don't see error, then it's tracked. Remove it from index but not from disk with `git rm --cached`. After that commit that change. Let me know if it helped you.