# add .env file to gitignore after taking it to live

Tags: git, gitignore

It is probably asked numerous time and answered even more time. I understand I need to use

> git rm --cached file_name

But my problem is that above command changes file status to deleted and if I push this commit to live and pull it my **.env** file will be deleted and hence my site will be down immediately. I cannot afford to go down even for a split second. What can be done in this case.

Thanks

Comment: Then don't do `git rm --cached`. Just use `git rm`

Answer (score 0):

just create copies of .env and rename based on your location & requirement.

Comment: So there is no GIT approach?

Comment: There is git way, if its already committed follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527982/applying-gitignore-to-committed-files then add this file into gitignore, assuming you have .env file on server present you just want not to send your .env file from local to live