# Git - skip gitignore files from being pushed to the repo

Tags: git

I have already committed a lot of files to my current repository (I haven't pushed them yet). However, many of these files that a lot of space and I shouldn't include them. I have updated my .gitignore accordingly to remove them, however my question is how to prevent these files from being pushed to the repository now?

I have tried git rm -r folder and it has actually deleted my entire folder on this. I just want to delete these files from the current commit. How can I do this?

Comment: Did you google and use the search for e.g. "gitignore after commit"?

Comment: Thanks, excellent suggestion! Found the response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527982/applying-gitignore-to-committed-files

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution here:

[Applying .gitignore to committed files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527982/applying-gitignore-to-committed-files)

"After editing .gitignore to match the ignored files, you can do git ls-files -ci --exclude-standard to see the files that are included in the exclude lists; you can then do git ls-files -ci --exclude-standard -z | xargs -0 git rm --cached to remove them from the repository (without deleting them from disk)."

Answer (score 0):

One option is to undo the commit and staging, you could try doing

```
git reset HEAD^
```

This command would reset the repo to previous commmit, however all the changes you did would still be available.

Comment: Thanks! I have actually done 3 commits which haven't been pushed. Does this mean I should use git reset HEAD^ 3 times to reach the previous state?