# git ignore file ending with certain suffix doesn't work

Tags: git, github, gitignore

In my repo's **.gitignore** file, I have :

```
*.xcuserstate
```

which means I would like to ignore all files ending with `.xcuserstate`.

I added that ignore rule long time ago. However, today I still see changes not stated for commit with following file

```
MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/john.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

Why? Why .gitignore doesn't work?

Comment: Was that file already committed at some point? `.gitignore` only affects untracked files.

Comment: @Ryan, yes, it has already been committed, what should I do to ignore it now?

Comment: You’ll have to make a commit that deletes it, then: `git rm --cached path/to/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.gitignore is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-is-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [gitignore doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

> gitignore - Specifies intentionally **untracked** files to ignore

Which means that `.gitignore` only affects untracked files.

To ignore an already tracked file refer to [Applying .gitignore to committed files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527982/applying-gitignore-to-committed-files)

Note that you will have to remove the file from the repository