# How to push a repository without a linked framework?

Tags: xcode, git, github

I recently made an iOS application in Xcode that uses the OpenCV framework. I would like to push this repository onto my Github page, but the framework contains files that are too large. Is there any way to remove that framework from the repository so that I can push it?

Comment: Wait: You added external libraries ("framework") to your sources? That would be a nono in and of itself. What files are so huge that Github rejects them?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thank you for pointing that out. Just realized that the framework was in my source. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the framework from my source and added it to the frameworks folder.
I then removed the framework from my initial commits, recommitted, and pushed.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to check in framework code into your project.

Use a [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file to specify directories that shouldn't be committed.

If you've already committed those files, you will have to rewrite history to reduce your repo size. It may be worth starting from a new history if not much work has been done.

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna want to filter (whether by directory or file type) it out using [git ignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527982/applying-gitignore-to-committed-files) if you need to remove files that were already committed.