# Best way to have default config using git

Tags: git

I have some files *.config.php which I want to keep "default" version in git remote, but in my local workstation I need to change it and if I put these files in .gitignore, still seeing the changes, since theres already a commit with these files.

I find some "bad" ways to keep these files untracked, but it is a quite difficult to do it for every each new developer that comes to development team, because everybody needs to type lots of "git rm --cached " for each config file. Anyway, whats the best way to have default config files and still being able to edit them without git see the changes?

Thanks

Comment: Keep a template config that is copied into place and modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there are ways to expedite the process:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7532131

```
apply-gitignore = !git ls-files -ci --exclude-standard -z | xargs -0 git rm --cached
```