# ignore files named npm-debug.log.XXXXXX in .gitignore

Tags: angular, git, npm, gitignore, npm-debug

Does anyone knows how to ignore this file from the repository with .gitignore?

[image]

I'm using Gitlab.

I've already tried this:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: This .gitignore line should work, but if you already pushed that kind of files to the remote repo, then you'll have to remove them from the remote, and then it will be ignore

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're right. Shouldn't you answered instead comment (because with answer I could mark as correct your answer)

Answer (score 8):

The gitignore line is correct, but git ignores it if some matching files are already pushed to the remote repository. It means the files are in the git index, so it will want to stage them until you remove it from index.

You could try to delete the file from the git index using

```
git rm --cached npm-debug.log.xxx
```

See more on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527982/applying-gitignore-to-committed-files/7528016) :)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks :) it was driving me crazy