# Remove virtualenv files from all previous commits after removing from repository

Tags: git, github, commit

When I started working on one of my Python projects, I forgot to add my `venv` virtual environment directory to my .gitignore. Now, my GitHub repository is showing the additions and deletions from that commit and does not give me a good sense of when I made major changes (the `venv` directory had 100,000+ lines of code).

I've already [updated my .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527982/applying-gitignore-to-committed-files) file and ran `git rm --cached .` followed by a `git add`, `commit`, and `push`.

Is there any way to remove the additions and deletions from all previous commits where my `venv` directory changed so that GitHub will no longer count these additions/deletions in my commits? I would like to keep the parts of commits that don't include `venv` and only get rid of the `venv` part of the commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch venv"
```

Please remember this rewrite the entire history of the branch so you have to force-push the branch and notify all users so that they force-pull it.

Comment: Would this get rid of all the past commits?

Comment: The command rewrites (not get rid of) all commits in the branch.

Comment: Need `-- --all` on the end to catch every ref. @JackMoody, history is immutable, the rewrites make new history and rehang the refs, so all the old commits are still there until garbage collection cleans them out (and filter-branch keeps a copy of the originals under `refs/original/`, to get rid of those `git filter-branch -f --setup exit` to just do a no-op cleanup.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! Why do users need to force-pull it as opposed to a normal pull?

Comment: Because the command rewrites the history (creates new commits instead of the current branch) and they have to **replace** (not merge, not rebase) their old branches with your new shiny branch.