# How to Setup .gitignore file to excludes bin/obj files in version control

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, github

When i push my code to github version control system, it includes with following files, which i don't want to be there in github repository. I have tried to customize .gitignore file to exclude these files but that did not help. What is the way to tell visual studio not to be included these files in "Team Explorer" property. I had to unstage these files to push the commit to the git repo.

[image: Team Explorer Property]

[image: Github Repo]

Comment: If the files were committed before adding to .gitignore, they remain commited. I think you can fix this by deleting them and then commiting the empty folder. If that doesn't work, I suggest making a new repo, and commiting to that one, having configured .gitignore before the files exist. Of course this would mean that you would loose your commit history.

Comment: If you git ignore is at the root of the solution then something like this in the git ignore: [Bb]in/ <newline> [Oo]bj/

Comment: Thank you guys for the reply, i had to recreate the git repo again to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

To Ignore files already committed. you need to

1. Edit `.gitignore`: to match files you need to ignore
2. Execute : `git rm --cached /path/to/file`

Resources :

1. [Untrack files already added to git](http://www.codeblocq.com/2016/01/Untrack-files-already-added-to-git-repository-based-on-gitignore/)
2. [Applying .gitignore to committed files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527982/applying-gitignore-to-committed-files)
3. [Remove a file from a Git repository without deleting it from the local filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143796/remove-a-file-from-a-git-repository-without-deleting-it-from-the-local-filesyste)