# Keep existing files from getting updates in Git

Tags: android, git, gitignore

I have a google_oauth_server.xml file in my project. It contains a client id, which I would like to not get checked into the repository.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Do not split into debug and release, as there is one server-->
<resources>
    <string name="google_server_client_id" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="false">
        ---my-code--
    </string>
</resources>
```

Instead, I want the file to exist in the repo, but with the words `YOUR CODE HERE` instead of the code.

I tried committing a file with the words `YOUR_CODE_HERE` instead of the code, then changing the words to my actual client id, and then adding the file to `.gitignore` to prevent it from getting committed, but it does not work, and git always tries to commit the file with the client id.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+track+file+ignore+future+changes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245961/208273

Answer (score 1):

[git-update-index](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_notes):

> Users often try to use the assume-unchanged and skip-worktree bits to
>   tell Git to ignore changes to files that are tracked. This does not
>   work as expected, since Git may still check working tree files against
>   the index when performing certain operations. In general, Git does not
>   provide a way to ignore changes to tracked files, so alternate
>   solutions are recommended.
>
> For example, if the file you want to change is some sort of config
>   file, the repository can include a sample config file that can then be
>   copied into the ignored name and modified. The repository can even
>   include a script to treat the sample file as a template, modifying and
>   copying it automatically.