# Have file pull on inital checkout, but then don't track further changes

Tags: git, gitignore

Lets say I have a file named "personal notes".
It is tracked on my initial push to my repo.
Then I want anyone who pulls the repo to get the "personal notes" file.
Then the users modify "personal notes" locally. 
How do I make it so that git will provide the initial file, but then no longer track changes to that file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep file in a Git repo, but don't track changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794931/keep-file-in-a-git-repo-but-dont-track-changes)

Comment: I really just want the file to be included when people pull but then never tracked by anyone afterwards.

Comment: I don't think that is possible without the user's intervention.You can create a startup script, that creates the file for you (which will be in .gitignore), but the user still has to run it.

Comment: Don't do this. Store a *template* file in the repository. Have your software copy the template to the actual file (which is then ignored), or just give everyone instructions to do that, after which they modify the notes all they like but it's still not in the repository. Trying to do this, with the `update-index` trick, just makes everyone miserable. Don't do it, and everyone is happy.

Comment: It was asked 2 hours ago: [Keep existing files from getting updates in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60995052/keep-existing-files-from-getting-updates-in-git/60995920#60995920)