# How to store .env file in github?

Tags: git, github, environment-variables, gitignore, environment

I have a node.js project with `.env` file in it. I pushed to github project, when in `.env` file was just a template. For example:

```
# Database credentials
DB_HOST=""
DB_USER=""
DB_PASSWORD=""
DB_DATABASE_NAME=""
```

Then I added `.env` file to `.gitignore`. Pushed again and now, when I filled `.env` file with credentials, `git status` command says

> modifed: .env

How can I store a template of `.env` file in github and ignore it's changes?

Comment: If you commit a file once and then add it to gitignore, git will continue tracking it.
[check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527982/applying-gitignore-to-committed-files)

Answer (score 6):

When we need to provide templates for environment files or secrets, we tend to add a .sample to the file name. That's has been mine and my workplace convention, and a lot of people follows it. So you can have files like
`.env.sample` and `secrets.sample`

Comment: In this case my code's users will must to do more actions: rename `.env.sample` to `.env`, fill it and only then start

Answer (score 2):

you can save your env template using `.env.example` file then push it to github, and add `.env` to `.gitignore`