# Removing __pycache__ from git repository

Tags: git, github, repository

How can I remove all `__pycache__` subdirectories in my repository using `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot remove files from existing commits: those commits are frozen for all time.  You can make sure you do not *add new* files to *future* commits, though.  Simply remove the files now, with `git rm -r --cached __pycache__`, and list `__pycache__` or `__pycache__/` in your `.gitignore` (creating this `.gitignore` file if needed).  Do this for each `__pycache__` directory; use your OS's facilities to find these (e.g., `find . -name __pycache__ -type d`).  Then `git add .gitignore` and `git commit` to commit the removal.

Note that any time anyone moves from any commit that *has* the files—where they'll be checked out—to a commit that *lacks* the files, they will have their entire `__pycache__` directory removed if Git is able to do that; at the least, any cached files that were committed and can be removed will be removed.  So the `--cached` in the `git rm -r --cached` above only speeds things up for *you* by avoiding the removal of the cached compiled files *this time*.  Others will have to rebuild their cache.

To make a *new and different repository* in which the `__pycache__` files were ever accidentally committed in the first place, use `git filter-branch` (which is now deprecated) or the newfangled `git filter-repo` (which is not yet distributed with Git).  Or, see any of these various existing questions and their answers, which you should already have found before you asked this:

- [Remove a file from a Git repository without deleting it from the local filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1143796/1256452)
- [Applying .gitignore to committed files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7527982/1256452)
- [How can I make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked, but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1274057/1256452)
- [Remove sensitive files and their commits from Git history](https://stackoverflow.com/q/872565/1256452)

Comment: first remove all __pycach__ so using this command $ find . -name __pycache__ -exec git rm -r --cached {} \;

Answer (score 1):

Add this in .gitignore, also in future you can use this handy [generator](https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore)

```
# Byte-compiled / optimized / DLL files
__pycache__/
*.py[cod]
*$py.class
```