# Is source repository in Xcode reliable?

Tags: git, xcode4

When I add some new files to my project (I've created a source repository for this project already), these files are not added to source repository at all. I go through my whole project and I found some of the files are in repository but some are not.Why like this? How to solve the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [XCode documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/SCM/SCM.html), check also the status of those non-versioned files.

[image: staus]

Some of those might be ignore by your source control tool (SVN or git) due to, for instance, a [`.gitignore` you can add to your project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258638/apply-git-gitignore-rules-to-an-existing-repository) (or like [this one](http://www.codedifferent.com/2011/05/01/coding-gitignore-for-xcode-4/)).

Answer (score 0):

Xcode uses git (by default) to manage version control. By default, new added files are not tracked by git. To add them to git, right click on them and click Source Control>Add. To commit the changes go File>Source Control>Commit... (or Command-Option-C)

Comment: The problem is if I added some files (.h and .m), The "A" status are not shown sometimes.

Comment: Once you add some files, have you tried right clicking them and clicking Source Control>Add? Does that not give the "A" status for them for you?