# Using Git to keep different versions of a file locally vs. in the master repository

Tags: git, github, gitignore

I have a PHP config file i'd like to manipulate locally but ignore those changes during `git commits` to my master repository. I had a `.gitignore` file which used to ignore this PHP file but bad things happen and now the `config.php` file is no longer being ignored and I can't remember how to re-ignore it.

I know people on SO say to use [`git rm --cached <filename>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258638/apply-git-gitignore-rules-to-an-existing-repository) but I can't for the life of me figure out how not to make `git rm...` keep deleting my config.php file.

I'm wondering if someone can list how to ignore my config.php such that I can keep editing it locally but these changes don't get added to the repo.

here's the entire contents of my `.gitignore`:

```
application/config.php
```

here's some php code in my `config.php` I'd like to keep local and **NOT** go in my master repo:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/";
//$config['base_url'] = "http://mysite.com/"; // this is the code and NOT
// "http://localhost" that i'd like to keep in my repo
```

This is what deletes my file:

1. `git rm --cached application/config.php`
2. make changes to the `application/config.php` file and another file (as a control)
3. `git commit -m 'config.php shouldn't be changed'`

   result: `2 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 370 deletions(-)` (`config.php` is 370 lines long)

Comment: Try committing immediately after the `git rm --cached`

Comment: @KevinBallard, the result of that is the same undesired result: `1 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 370 deletions(-)`

Comment: Shouldn't that be **application/config.php** in .gitignore?

Comment: @stark, thanks for pointing this out, that's just a copy/paster error, my real code is lacking the 1st backslash, i've now updated the question,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved my own problem. I actually need this:

[`git update-index --assume-unchanged <filename>`](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/18/temporarily-ignoring-files.html)

Assuming the .gitignore and config.php files being specified as above in my question, 
here's the complete workflow:

1. `git update-index --assume-unchanged application/config.php`
2. `git add -A`
3. `git commit -m 'now config.php will be ignored'`
4. `git push origin master`

Now `http://localhost` will remain in the config.php on my local copy of the repo and `http://my-site.com` will be preserved in the config.php in my master repo.

Comment: If that's what you wanted, your question is quite misleading; it suggested that you wanted to stop tracking config.php but keep the local file.

Comment: @Infiltrator sorry didn't mean to mislead, thanks for pointing this out, i edited my question to make clear that I want the config.php file to remain in the master repository

Comment: That's cool.  Just to let you know that when you ask for A, people are going to answer for A; whereas you might want B.

Comment: Do i need to this every time i commit from my local machine? Or the `update-index` will work for all the future commits?

Comment: Using " git checkout . " will revert the file anyways

Comment: @timpeterson Is the .gitignore even needed in this case? I don't understand what it's doing here

Comment: @holastello correct, it worked for me without using it

Comment: The file seems to get overwritten anyways every time I check out a new branch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `config.php` in your .gitignore file.

If, however, you've actually added config.php to your repo, you'll need to `git rm` it and then commit, and then recreate it (or you can make a copy and then copy back).

Comment: config.php is in my .gitignore file