# Git Merge with ignored migrations files

Tags: django, git, migration

I've started using `git` recently for a Django web app. I am also using the South Migration app for Django.

I have 2 branches - `develop` and `master`. I added new features to `develop` and now I would like to merge `develop` into `master`.

The problem is I have migration folders and I don't want them to be merge. For that reason, I added a `.gitignore` file in the main folder of the `master` branch and the `develop` branch.

`.gitignore`:

```
*.pyc
!/.gitignore
acpkinballmanageevents/migrations/
acpkinballmanageleague/migrations/
acpkinballmanagemembers/migrations/
acpkinballmanageteams/migrations/
blog/migrations/
managelayerslider/migrations/
managesite/migrations/
```

But it asks me to merge some `.pyc` file and files in the `/migrations/` folders....

Is it possible to not merge them or is it recommended to merge the migration files?

EDIT:

Here is my `.gitattributes` file:

```
acpkinballmanageevents/migrations/* merge=ours
acpkinballmanageleague/migrations/* merge=ours
acpkinballmanagemembers/migrations/* merge=ours
acpkinballmanageteams/migrations/* merge=ours
blog/migrations/* merge=ours
managelayerslider/migrations/* merge=ours
managesite/migrations/* merge=ours
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have these files previously tracked in git, they are already recorded in git’s view of the branch content. Git still knows about the files and will ask you to merge, even if you try and ignore them.

You could have the files forcefully ignored - see [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring) and specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3262033) on how to use `git ls-files` to have all the files that match your newly introduced `.gitignore` excluded automatically.

Alternatively, and what seems to me like the better approach in your case – you could use git attributes to describe specific merge strategies for the files.  See http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Merge-Strategies

You don’t want to merge the migration files from *develop* to *master*, say, you can setup an attribute file like this (under *master*):

```
----- migration/.gitattributes ----
* merge=ours
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer!!! So I copied this and added a .gitattributes file in my master branch (root). And then I tried to merge. I still the migration files in the changes... Also, I would like the master branch to not merge a file called: local_settings.py Thanks, alot Ara!

Comment: @AraSivaneswaran I don't think you read the gitattribute link in the answer - it's best to read the whole chapter. The file is a `.gitattributes` file, not a `.gitignore` file. Also note that `----- migration ...` is not part of the file.

Comment: oups I meant to write .gitattributes. I got mixed up -.-. Ok I thought it was like a comment :S. Do I have to keep the * merge=ours? ANd yeah, I will read the whole chapter, I thought only the last paragraph was about the .gitattributes. Thanks once again, Ara